# bonecp keeps so many sessions and processes inactive

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, connection, bonecp

I have used bone-cp 0.8.0 release.jar, even though there is no connections is running on DB, still processes, sessions are showing drastically.

Below is the config:

```
boneCPConfig.setUsername(obj.getProperty("username"));
boneCPConfig.setPassword(obj.getProperty("password"));
boneCPConfig.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(0);
boneCPConfig.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(10);
boneCPConfig.setPartitionCount(1);
boneCPConfig.setAcquireIncrement(2);
boneCPConfig.setConnectionTimeoutInMs(10000);
boneCPConfig.setIdleMaxAgeInSeconds(300);
boneCPConfig.setStatementsCacheSize(20);
boneCPConfig.setLazyInit(false);
boneCPConfig.setMaxConnectionAgeInSeconds(0);
boneCPConfig.setTransactionRecoveryEnabled(false);
boneCPConfig.setDisableConnectionTracking(false);
boneCPConfig.setCloseConnectionWatch(false);
boneCPConfig.setAcquireRetryAttempts(5);
boneCPConfig.setCloseConnectionWatchTimeoutInMs(0);
boneCPConfig.setIdleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes(10);
```

Can anyone help me out? Is there any config that needs to be set to remove inactive sessions which holds process?